# How to go from one JFrame to another Jframe with a JButton

Tags: jframe, jbutton

I have removed all of the code besides the JFrame stuff so it would be easier to see. I want to be able to click a JButton, and that should take me to an existing JFrame in another class. I will provide two classes below. I added the action listener however it does nothing.

```js
package testjframe;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


/**
 *
 * 
 */
public class TestJframe 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        JFrame P1Frame = new JFrame ( "Project 1" );
        
        P1Frame.pack();
        P1Frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        P1Frame.setSize(new Dimension(800, 900));
        P1Frame.setLayout(null);
        P1Frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        P1Frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        P1Frame.setLayout ( new FlowLayout () );
        P1Frame.setVisible ( true );
        P1Frame.setResizable(false);
        
        JButton f2 = new JButton("Frame 2"); 
        P1Frame.add(f2);
        
        f2.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
         new NewForm();        
        }
        });             
    }   
}
```

```js
package testjframe;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 *
 * 
 */
class NewForm 
{
        public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        
        JFrame P2Frame = new JFrame ( "Project 1 second Frame" );
        
        P2Frame.pack();
        P2Frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.RED);
        P2Frame.setSize(new Dimension(800, 900));
        P2Frame.setLayout(null);
        P2Frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        P2Frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        P2Frame.setLayout ( new FlowLayout () );
        P2Frame.setVisible ( true );
        P2Frame.setResizable(false);
    }
    }
```

Comment: In most case, don't, instead consider using a `CardLayout` to switch between different views

Comment: The long answer would be to create a method in each class which could create the instance of the frame and simply call it when needed

Comment: In this case, everything needs to almost remain like this. My instructor is very picky..

Comment: I am able to switch between just one frame now, The issue is because I have two main methods, how can I eliminate this?